# Python CSV: TypeError unsupported operand "cant sum list"

Tags: python, string, list, csv, type-conversion

My code is returning:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Justin/Desktop/Program 5/Weather_Program#5.py", line 111, in <module>
    month = sum(january)/10
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I know exactly where and why this error is occurring, but I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

The data I'm reading in the `csv` is dates in left column and precipitation in right column. `20000101` would be january 1st 2001 and 0 would be 0 inches of rain. Na is to be excluded, which works correctly in the second while loop. Once I convert the numbers to floats I run into the error

```
20000101    0

20000102    NA

20000103    12.2

20000104    0.3
```

code:

```
import csv

january   = []
february  = []
march     = []
april     = []
may       = []
june      = []
july      = []
august    = []
september = []
october   = []
november  = []
december  = []

def read_cell(column, row):
    """Input x & y coordinate for CSV file: Returns information in cell"""
    with open('precipitation.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        y_count = 0
        for n in reader:
            if y_count == row:
                cell = n[column]
                return cell
            y_count += 1


stormy = 0
row_number = 0

while stormy < 1:
    with open('precipitation.csv', 'r') as f:
            date = read_cell(0,row_number)
            rain = read_cell(1,row_number)
            if date == None:
                stormy += 1
                break

            elif date[4:6] == "01":
                january.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1                

            elif date[4:6] == "02":
                february.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1

            elif date[4:6] == "03":
                march.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1

            elif date[4:6] == "04":
                april.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1

            elif date[4:6] == "05":
                may.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1               

            elif date[4:6] == "06":
                june.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1               

            elif date[4:6] == "07":
                july.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1

            elif date[4:6] == "08":
                august.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1               

            elif date[4:6] == '09':
                september.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1               

            elif date[4:6] == '10':
                october.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1               

            elif date[4:6] == '11':
                november.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1

            elif date[4:6] == '12':
                december.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1

while "NA" in january:
    january.remove("NA")

    while "NA" in february:
        february.remove("NA")    

        while "NA" in march:
            march.remove("NA")    

            while "NA" in april:
                april.remove("NA")

                while "NA" in may:
                    may.remove("NA")

                    while "NA" in june:
                        june.remove("NA")

                        while "NA" in july:
                            july.remove("NA")

                            while "NA" in august:
                                august.remove("NA")

                                while "NA" in september:
                                    september.remove("NA")

                                    while "NA" in october:
                                        october.remove("NA")

                                        while "NA" in november:
                                            november.remove("NA")

                                            while "NA" in december:
                                                december.remove("NA")


january = [float(i) for i in january]
january = sum(float(january))/10
print(january)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think this is the situation you have

```
>>> sum([0,'NA', 12.2, 0.3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

You can filter the values before passing to sum like this. It's called a "generator expression"

```
>>> sum(x for x in [0,'NA', 12.2, 0.3] if x != 'NA')
12.5
```

ie.

```
month = sum(x for x in january if x != 'NA')/10
```

Comment: This is just a sample of the list. I'm working with 5000+ cells so this will not work.

Comment: @Wakedude, it doesn't have to be a literal list - any expression that returns a sequence will do.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it for me. Really appreciate the help.